# Manually triggering a quartz job with arguments that is hosted in a windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I have created a Quartz server running in a windows service that has various scheduled jobs.

However, there is one job that I need to be triggered manually from an event in my web application UI.

**Quartz.NET job:**

```
public class IntensiveJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Get job parameters here... BUT HOW?!

        // Do some intensive processing here...
    }
}
```

**Action that I need to trigger the job in:**

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttPost]
    public ActionResult Run()
    {
        // Need to be able to trigger the intensive job here... 
        // Ideally with some arguments too... E.g:
        var job = new IntensiveJob();
        job.Execute();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on best way to implement this or alternative approaches would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that best fits your problem is to create a trigger manually that gets executed now by the scheduler. The problem that arises is if you need to have different data in your trigger each time it is created to be passed to the scheduler. The trigger factory that is created by quartz will always produce an identical object when asked for a new trigger. You would have to instantiate an instance of the Trigger Impl with the necessary details and pass that to the scheduler to run. An example in Java would look something like:

```
JobDetailImpl jdi = new JobDetailImpl();
jdi.setJobClass(SomeClassWithJob);//The class that contains the task to done.
SimpleTriggerImpl sti = new SimpleTriggerImpl();
sti.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
sti.setRepeatInterval(1);
sti.setRepeatCount(0);
context.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jdi,sti); //pseudocode here
```

The key thing is to use quartz for the scheduling and not to just insert data into the database. Also, each of the items require a name and group.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. However, with my scheduler being hosted in a Windows service, there would be no way of adding this trigger to the scheduler. I guess the only solution would be to move to an ADO job store and add the trigger record to the database.

Comment: A requirement of this solution is that you are importing the quartz library and running the scheduler on the same environment. There is likely a similar way to get the scheduler in C#/.NET as in Java. It should look something like: `IJobExecutionContext.Get(Scheduler).ScheduleJob(IJobDetail, ITrigger)`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, running the scheduler in the same environment is not an option for me, it will hosted on an isolated server in a windows service. However, hooking up a database driven job/trigger store would allow me to do what you have suggested with regards to creating a new trigger which will start almost immediately. I'll look into it. Thanks for your help.